# tensorflow more metrics with custom estimator

Tags: tensorflow, metrics, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

I created custom estimator that used `binary_classification_head()` under the hood. All works good but the problem is with visible metrics. I'm using logging with level `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)` and tensorboard but I only see loss value.
I added this code but it helps nothing.

```
def my_accuracy(labels, predictions):
    return {'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions['logistic'])}
classifier = tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(classifier, my_accuracy)
```

Do you know some other way to add metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place relevant metrics function inside your `model_fn`.

For example:

```
tf.summary.image('input_image', input_image, max_outputs)

for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES):
        tf.summary.histogram(v.name, v)
```

Metrics that include `update_op`, like accuracy of f1 score need to be fed to `eval_metric_ops`. Slicing is used because they output two values, metric value and update operation

```
f1 = tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score(labels, predictions, num_thresholds)
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions)
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])

eval_metric_ops = {
    'f1_score': f1,
    'accuracy': accuracy
}

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                  loss=loss,
                                  train_op=train_op,
                                  eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
                                  )
```

`eval_metric_ops` dict could be fed both in train mode and eval mode.

In case you're using canned estimator, you can jus use add_metrics

Edit:
As per official documentation , you can use `binary_classification_head` with canned estimator or inside model_fn func which returns estimator_spec. See

```
my_head = tf.contrib.estimator.binary_classification_head()
my_estimator = tf.estimator.DNNEstimator(
    head=my_head,
    hidden_units=...,
    feature_columns=...)
```

In this case you should be able to add metrics even without add_metrics func

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I use the binary_classification_head() instead of tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec which don't have the eval_metric_ops parameter.
It would be pity if one have to abandon it only because of metrics.